# jquery check if string has been deleted from textarea and remove option from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using jquery to detect an @ symbol been inserted into a textarea. When this is detected an ajax request is fired to the server to retrieve a list of users. A user would then click on the username and it will be appended to the textarea as follows and also added to a select so that I may notify the relevant users of this note;

```
$(document).on('click', '#fetchUsers li',function(e){
        var username = $( this ).text();
        var user_id = $( this ).attr('data-user-id');
        $('textarea.addNote').val(function(_, val){return val + username; });
        $(this).parent('ul#fetchUsers').html('');

        $('#addAUsertoNote')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",user_id)
                .text(username));

    });
```

Now the problem I have is that if I delete the string @userone from the textarea this option value is in the options list but it shouldn't be. Does anyone know if and how it is possible check if a username has been deleted and remove this from the option group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach, add keydown event and each time check if each user is in textarea:

```
$('textarea.addNote').keydown(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var note = self.val();
    var users = $('#addAUsertoNote option').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        if (!note.match("@" + user)) {
            $('#addAUsertoNote option:contains(' + user + ')').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: will this match for the @ symbol in the select? as this will not be in the select text.

Comment: @001221 it only check for @ in textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to exclude already clicked usernames from the next list of users?

I would extend the function that retrieves the list to scan the content of the textarea for @\w+ strings and disable any list options that match.

You could also look at the multi-select menus provided by Chosen: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#optgroup-support